# Execute Oracle Stored procedure with Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to get a ResultSet from an Oracle SP (I already did it with SQL Server).

The code I used to execute the stored procedure is :

```
public static ResultSet ExecuteGetAnalyseOrdon(Connection conn, int LigneIndex, String TypeAlerte)
            throws SQLException
    {
         String OraQuery = "{call   Package_Name.SP_Name(?,?,?,?,?)}";
         CallableStatement stmt = null;
         ResultSet rset = null;
         stmt = conn.prepareCall(OraQuery);
         stmt.setInt(1, LigneIndex);
         stmt.setString(2,  "H");
         stmt.setString(3,  null);
         stmt.setString(4,  null);
         stmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
         stmt.executeUpdate();
         rset = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(5);
         while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println("Test");
               System.out.println(rset.getString(0)); 

         }
         return rset;   
    }
```

The code of the Stored procedure is very long but this is it declaration

```
PROCEDURE SP_Name (Param1   IN INT,
                   Param2 IN VARCHAR2,
                   Param3 IN VARCHAR2,
                   Param4 IN VARCHAR2,
                   cur_res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

When executing my java code i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01578: bloc de données ORACLE altéré (fichier # 201, bloc # 1920)
ORA-01110: fichier de données 201 : 'C:\APP\ACER\ORADATA\ORCL\TEMP01.DBF'

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:288)
    at betaAutomationOracle.ExecuteGetAnalyseOrdo.ExecuteGetAnalyseOrdon(ExecuteGetAnalyseOrdo.java:28)
    at betaAutomationOracle.ExecuteScript.main(ExecuteScript.java:104)
```

Any help, please ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, nope, it didn't

Comment: PS : I'm not connected as sys in the session where I execute the SP

Comment: try this link please and if it wasent helpfull tell me to continue helping you https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9530553800346466993